# Marklogic unstemmed search is not working as expected

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using ML 8.

'unfiltered' cts:search is not working as expected for diacritic words with 'stemmed' option

Find the below example.

I have inserted the below xml in ML DB with uri /a.xml

**case 1:**

```
<root>
<a>FSM İlmî Araştırmalar İnsan ve Toplum Bilimleri Dergisi</a>
</root>
```

and the query i'm using

```
cts:search(/*,cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("a"), "FSM İlmî Araştırmalar İnsan ve Toplum Bilimleri Dergisi",("case-insensitive","stemmed")),'unfiltered')
```

Above query results in the **empty result** and if I'm opting `unstemmed` then it works fine.

While in some other cases it's working fine with `stemmed` option. for example

**case 2:**

```
<root>
<c>Życie Literackie</c>
</root>
```

same query with `stemmed` option working fine in this case.

So, My question is why `stemmed` option is not working as expected in the first case and why it's working fine in the second case.

also, what is the role of `stemmed` in the diacritic search?

**case 3:**
I have inserted normal string as below with uri /d.xml

```
<root>
<c>Zycie Literackie</c>
</root>
```

and running query-

```
cts:search(/*,cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("c"), "Zycie Literackie",("case-insensitive","stemmed")),'unfiltered')
```

but it returns the diacritic and normal string both. the result looks like as below

```
 <root>
<c>Życie Literackie</c>
</root> 
<root>
<c>Zycie Literackie</c>
</root>
```

It should return only normal string `Zycie Literackie`.

Similarly, inserted an XML file as below

**case 4:**

```
<root>
<data>Türkiye Araştırmaları Literatür Dergisi</data>
</root>
```

and the query is-

```
cts:search(
doc(),
cts:element-word-query(
    xs:QName('data'),
    "Turkiye Araştırmaları Literatür Dergisi",
    ('case-insensitive','wildcarded','diacritic-sensitive','unstemmed')
),
"unfiltered"
)
```

Then, it results in the empty result. If searching with words like `Turkiye`, `Araştırmaları` or `Literatür`, it returns the correct result.

Why is the desired search result not found with given string in the query while it works fine with the single words?

.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for Case 3: When you do not explicitly specify "diacritic-sensitive" in options, text node content determines whether it should perform "diacritic-sensitive" search or "diacritic-insensitive" search. If word(s) in the text node contains diacritic characters, then "diacritic-sensitive" search is performed otherwise not. Same applies for case sensitivity.